# How do i use the jquery on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I will not copy all the example/s code/s to here its long.
But this is the jquery demo page:

[Demo Page](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?9dPATS7v)

And i want to add to my site the example with the Latest News in red with the scrolling text inside.
In the demo page there is link for the source/s of the examples.

In my site i have this code now that read text line by line from a text file and scroll up the text and above it there is a timer count back untill the next update.

I want somehow to make that the text from the text file to read it line by line and add it to the Latest News example from the demo page so it will be on my site the same visual and way it is in the demo page.

This is my code that is working but now i want that the text file each line i read to be show in the Latest News like in the demo page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://risq.github.io/jquery-advanced-news-ticker/assets/js/jquery.newsTicker.js"></script>
<script>
    var count = 300;
    var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

    function timer() {
    count = count - 1;
    if (count == -1) {
            clearInterval(counter);
            return;
    }

    var seconds = count % 60;
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
    minutes %= 60;
    hours %= 60;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = hours + " Hours " + minutes + " Minutes and " + seconds + " Seconds left untill the next news update."; // watch for spelling
    }
    function news(){
   $('body').find('.newsticker').remove();//It will clear old data if its present 
   var file = "http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/theme/test.txt";
    $.get(file, function (txt) {
            //var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
            var lines = txt.split("\n");
            $ul = $('<ul class="newsticker" />');
            for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
                //save(lines[i]); // not sure what this does
                $ul.append('<li>' + lines[i] + '</li>'); //here 
            }
            //$ul.appendTo('body').newsTicker({
            $ul.appendTo('div.wcustomhtml').newsTicker({
                row_height: 48,
                max_rows: 2,
                speed: 6000,
                direction: 'up',
                duration: 1000,
                autostart: 1,
                pauseOnHover: 1
            });
    });
    }
    $(function() {
    news();
    setInterval(function(){
      news();
    },30000)  // it will call every 1 min you can change it
    });
</script>
<br><br><span id="timer"></span><br><br>
```

Do i need to download the demo example files ? Or i can use a link like i did in my code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What you need to run the plugin?

All you need to know is on the [project's GitHub](https://github.com/vaakash/jquery-easy-ticker) (:

**What you need:**

- Jquery 1.7+
- jquery.easy-ticker scripts
- know the syntax
- run with jQuery

### Syntax

```
<div class="myWrapper">
    <ul>
        <li>List element 1</li>
        <li>List element 2</li>
        <li>List element 3</li>
        <li>List element 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

or

<div class="myWrapper">
    <div>
        <div>Element 1</div>
        <div>Element 2</div>
        <div>Element 3</div>
        <div>Element 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Run with jQuery

```
$('.myWrapper').easyTicker({
    // list of properties
});
```

### -[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/74Cqu/)

### Where?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
// you should add scripts and styles here
</head>
<body>
// you should add all website structure here

// now run scripts here
</body>
</html>
```

Example: http://pastebin.com/S3LBtSue

### About linking

**Jquery:**

you can take from Google: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide?hl=pt-br#jquery

or download and host on your website: http://jquery.com/download/

_

**Other js's**

you can host on Google Drive: http://www.komku.org/2013/08/how-to-host-javascript-or-css-files-on-google-drive.html

maybe you can find here: www.cdnjs.com

or download and host  on your website